# How to pass the parameters from react-native-webview to the javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

Trying to send the parameters from the react-native-WebView to the javascript function.

tried injectedjs which didn't work

Should be able to pass the params from the webview to the javascript function.

Comment: <WebView source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/ICFPackage/ICFPackage/index.html' }}
                    originWhitelist={["*"]}`enter code here`
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    scalesPageToFit={true}
                    allowFileAccess={true} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `injectedJavaScript` in Webview

This is the prop of the  `React-Native-WebView`.

**Usage**

```js
const message = "webview"
let jsCode = `jsfunc(message);`;
<WebView
          source={{ uri: "www.example.com" }}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          ref={webview => {this.myWebview = webview;}} 
          injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
        />
```

If you want to send data to the homepage, you can use post-message.

**Usage**

```js
 // receive message from homepage
 onMessage( event ) {
        console.log( event.nativeEvent.data );
    }

    // send message
    sendPostMessage() {
        console.log( "Sending post message" );
        this.myWebview.postMessage( "Post message" );
    }
...
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.sendPostMessage()}>
                    <Text>Send post message</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <WebView
                    style={{flex: 1}}
                    source={{ uri:"www.example.com" }}
                    ref={( webView ) => this.myWebview = webView}
                    onMessage={this.onMessage}
                />
```

Comment: Can this be done without using injectedJS and passing the parameters to a javascript function?

Comment: You can send the data to the homepage by message and receive the data through the listener and put the data into the function.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you said. I didn't really understand.

Comment: @AishwaryaRM I edited my answer.

Comment: @AishwaryaRM Why has the 'V' sign been turned off in my answer?